# разбить массив и вывести элемент в цикл

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет. У меня есть массив, мне нужно разделить значения ключа value2 в массиве и вывести 2 элемент из     value2 в цикле

Пример:

```
$arr = [
[
'value1' => 'A',
'value2' => '1:2:3:4'
],
[
'value1' => 'B',
'value2' => '1:2:3:4'
]
];
shuffle($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
$str = explode(':', $arr[$i]['value2']);
echo $arr[$i]['value1'];
echo $str[$i]; как тут вывести 2 элемент
}
```

Нужно вывести 2 значения (рандом) из     value2
Например A 2 3 B 2 4

Как это делать..помогите если не трудно.

Comment: Начни с `print_r($str)`

Comment: https://onlinephp.io/c/c0cc7

Answer (score 0):

> 2 значения (рандом) из value2

```
$arr = [
  [
    'value1' => 'A',
    'value2' => '1:2:3:4'
  ],
  [
    'value1' => 'B',
    'value2' => '1:2:3:4'
  ]
];
shuffle($arr);
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $str = explode(':', $elem['value2']);
  $rndKeys = array_rand($str, 2);
  echo $elem['value1'].$str[$rndKeys[0]].$str[$rndKeys[1]].PHP_EOL; // B23 A34
}
```

Comment: TemirStack, чюспасибо работает.